# Unable to understand angularjs dependency error

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement a custom filter. I am getting a dependency error from angularjs.

Below is my code:

```js
angular.module('Test', [])
  .controller('TestController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.myDate = 1456106575956;
  }])
  .filter('utcToDate', function(pUTCString) {
    return function(pUTCString) {
        return new Date(pUTCString);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="Test" ng-controller="TestController">
  {{myDate | utcToDate:myDate }}
</body>
```

Comment: Add the error you are getting. Plunker would provide u quick answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS should be

```
  angular.module('Test', [])
  .controller('TestController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.myDate = 1456106575956;
  }])
  .filter('utcToDate', function() {
    return function(pUTCString) {
        return new Date(pUTCString);
    }
});
```

HTML is fine, but can also be written as

```
 <body ng-app="Test" ng-controller="TestController">
  {{myDate | utcToDate }}
</body>
```

> What went wrong?

You're not required to specify a parameter while defining the function for a custom filter as you have done here

```
.filter('utcToDate', function(pUTCString) {
```

More on [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) from the official documentation.

**Here is a [Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bFiqVYkyn3sQKmJM8JD2?p=preview)**

Comment: You're welcome! Please select it as an answer if you are satisfied with it, so it can be closed as a question.